# dropdow list MVC, com item selecionado

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, dropdownlist

Tenho um `dropdowlist` que carrega `RamosDeAtidade`, quero saber como eu faço pra na minha view Edit, ja vir selecionado o ramo que eu cadastrei, na minha Controller, na `Action Edit` Está assim:

```
var cliente = _clienteAppService.ObterPorId(id ?? Guid.Empty);
ViewBag.RamoAtividadeId = new SelectList(_ramoDeAtividadeAppService.ObterTodos(), 
         "RamoDeAtividadeId", 
         "Descricao", 
          cliente.RamoAtividadeId);
return PartialView(cliente);
```

na minha view, eu fiz o seguinte razor:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.RamoAtividadeId, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.RamoAtividadeId,  new { @class = "form-control-sm", style = "max-width:156px; padding:0" })
```

desse modo, nunca vem selecionnado o ramo que eu cadastrei.

Comment: você já fez isso passando o terceiro parâmetro na classe `SelectList`!

Comment: mas ainda assim, não vem selecionado o ramo de atividade que eu cadastrei. :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Na verdade você já está fazendo isso porque está passando o terceiro parametro é só fazer um ajuste na `View` e utilizar `DropDownList`, ***exemplo***:

```
@Html.DropDownList("RamoAtividadeId", null, null, new { @class = "form-control-sm", style = "max-width:156px; padding:0" })
```

**ou** pode utilizar e o `cast` para `SelectList`, ***exemplo***:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.RamoAtividadeId, ViewBag.RamoAtividadeId as SelectList,  new { @class = "form-control-sm", style = "max-width:156px; padding:0" })
```

Comment: agora deu certo. Obrigado!